# web service is unable to return back to default page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web, service

I have asmx web service hosted on IIS and its purpose is to authenticate logined user.

when I run my code using visual studio and debug service is successfully called and authenticate user from DB but it is unable to transfer control back to my code that has default page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");



        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["Uri"] = Request.UrlReferrer;


        }

        this.hdnLoginStatus.InnerHtml = "";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            new DAS().AuthenticateRequest();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["LoginStatus"] == null)
                return;

            var key = (AuthWS.LoginStatus)HttpContext.Current.Items["LoginStatus"];
            string msg = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("Message", key.ToString()) ?? "";
            this.ShowMessage(msg, MessageType.Warning);
            this.hdnLoginStatus.InnerHtml = "SignedOutForcefully";    
        }

    }

    protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?key=" + (AuthWS.LoginStatus)HttpContext.Current.Items["LoginStatus"]);
    }
```

Comment: share your code of login form

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: no i am not getting any error. its just waiting for localhost to response. and after some time Problem loading page appears